# How to determine how much my program have been delayed by OS overhead

Tags: linux, windows, delay, scheduler, multitasking

I am looking for a way to determine how much time my program have been delayed by the OS scheduler. E.g. how long did it take since my program was last scheduled.
Let's assume that a for loop counts to 100 and my program is paused at 42 to let other programs run. When my program starts counting from 43 again I would assume the OS scheduler knows for how long I was "paused" and with some luck this information is stored somewhere for me to read somewhere else in my program.

I am looking for a method of getting this information this under both linux and windows. Programming language of choice is C.
The purpose of this is to know how "realtime" my program was running during the last n seconds.

Comment: How much precision do you require? `time` may suffice depending on what you actually need.

Comment: Yes, I am aware that I can use time, but I might be tricked if my own program uses a bit too much time here and there. I would prefer something a bit more "from the depths of the OS" if you understand what I mean.

Comment: I had a similar question. But, the answer is not short. Infact, the context switch might happen in-between each loop too, in that case, you might not be able to find it. Difficult way to find your answer is to put debug in scheduler[kernel] itself:(

Comment: Yes the context switch can happen anywhere. I want to know the max and minimum delay time for that. I suppose the OS store that somewhere.